# Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: DiscoveryService: mychannel error: access denied

Tags: rest, express, ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric

I am using Hyperledger fabric 2.2 on ubuntu. I am trying to create REST API using express.js with the help of this [article](https://kctheservant.medium.com/rework-an-implementation-of-api-server-for-hyperledger-fabric-network-fabric-v2-2-a747884ce3dc).

My fabric network and apiserver.js is on same server.

1. Does that mean that i can use localhost instead of the IP address of fabric host by the given suggestion in mentioned article.

if i can use local host there is no need to change connection profile right?

so, i tried to query using the command **curl http://localost:8080/api/queryallcars**

but i got errors curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

& error: [DiscoveryService]: send[mychannel] - Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: DiscoveryService: mychannel error: access denied

Also, I have enabled discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true} in apiserver.js file.

where am i doing wrong?.

Thank You in Advance!

UPDATE: Answer given by @Jerome O'Mahony worked for me!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i can use local host there is no need to change connection profile right?

Just remember that everytime that you build your network, a new client connection profile (CCP) file will be created. Therefore, you will have to copy the most recent version to where your connection code for the API is. Also you will need to perform the register Admin and Register User for your wallet (delete the old ones). You can either copy the CCP file or else create  a symbolic link in your API code that points to the latest version in the peer directory under organizations.

Is your REST API actually running on port 8080. Create a test page that returns "Hello World" in JSON so that you can at least verify that the mechanics of the API work before worrying about whether it can connect to Hyperledger.

Also, it is best to use a small command line test program to see if you can connect to, and query,  the Hyperledger network before adding the complication of adding an API in between.

Comment: Your advice about copying recent version of CCP did the job. THANK YOU!!. I wanted to vote your answer but it seems i dont have enough reputation to do that.                                                                                                          Also, I have a question about whether it is mentioned in the Fabric documentation that everytime when we build a network, a CCP file will be created and to build an API, one have to copy that same file in apiserver folder. If that point is available in documentation or any other reference/article, Can you share the link??

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. I don't ever remember reading anywhere to remind you to do this everytime that you build the network. I learnt the hard way. Using a symbolic link is a good way to cross reference the original CCP file, especially if you are at a stage where you are creating the same network many times.